# Elm decode json in different format

Tags: json, elm

I try to decode some json in elm.
The object I´m receiving could be in two different shapes.
**First case:**

```
{
    ...
    "ChipId": "NotSet"
    ...
}
```

**Second Case:**

```
{
    ...
    "ChipId": {
      "Item": "0000000000"
    },
    ...
}
```

So the first one can easily be decoded with `field "ChipId" string` but in case it´s the complex object it fails.
I already tried it with `Decode.andThen` but I couldn't solve it.

Thank you for your help!

### Update 1 - decoder that fails

The way I tried was by using a `Maybe`.

```
chipIdDecoder : Decoder String
chipIdDecoder =
    let
        chipIdIdDecoder : Decoder String
        chipIdIdDecoder =
            field "ChipId" (field "Fields" (firstElementDecoder string))

        chooseChipId : Maybe String -> Decoder String
        chooseChipId c =
            case c of
                Just id ->
                    case id of
                        "ChipId" ->
                            chipIdIdDecoder

                        _ ->
                            succeed ""

                Nothing ->
                    fail "Chip Id is invalid"
    in
    nullable (field "ChipId" string)
        |> andThen chooseChipId
```

I suppose the problem here is that `Maybe` expects something or `null` and not something or something else. ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***tl;dr:** use [`oneOf`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/1.1.3/Json-Decode#oneOf)*

A good approach to writing json decoders in Elm is to start from the smallest parts, write decoders that decode each of those parts independently, then move up to the next level and write a decoder for that by putting together the smaller pieces you've already made.

Here, for example, I would start by writing a decoder to handle the two possible forms of `"ChipId"` separately. The first is just a string, which of course comes out of the box with `elm/json`, so that's easy enough. The other is an object with a single field, which we'll just decode into a simple `String`:

```
chipIdObjectDecoder : Decoder String
chipIdObjectDecoder =
    field "Item" string
```

Then we need to put them together, which seems like the part you're struggling most with. Here the [`oneOf`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/1.1.3/Json-Decode#oneOf) function comes to our rescue, whose description says:

> Try a bunch of different decoders. This can be useful if the JSON may come in a couple different formats.

Sounds like exactly what we need! To try both the `string` decoder and our `chipIdObjectDecoder` we can write:

```
eitherStringOrChipIdObject : Decoder String
eitherStringOrChipIdObject =
    oneOf [ string, chipIdObjectDecoder ]
```

And then finally we need to decode the `"ChipId"` field itself:

```
field "ChipId" eitherStringOrChipIdObject
```

All this put together in a single function:

```
chipIdDecoder : Decoder String
chipIdDecoder =
    let
        chipIdObjectDecoder : Decoder String
        chipIdObjectDecoder =
            field "Item" string

        eitherStringOrChipIdObject : Decoder String
        eitherStringOrChipIdObject =
            oneOf [ string, chipIdObjectDecoder ]
    in
    field "ChipId" eitherStringOrChipIdObject
```

Or to simplify it a little bit, since the above is rather verbose:

```
chipIdDecoder : Decoder String
chipIdDecoder =
    let
        chipIdObjectDecoder =
            field "Item" string
    in
    field "ChipId" (oneOf [ string, chipIdObjectDecoder ])
```

As a last note, since it's not clear whether your code is overly simplified. If the `"ChipId"` object cannot be reduced to a simple string, you'll have to use a common type that can hold both a `String` and a `ChipIdObject`, and `map` the decoded values to that common type. `eitherStringOrChipIdObject` could then be something like this:

```
type alias ChipIdObject = { ... }

type ChipId
    = ChipIdString String
    | ChipIdObject ChipIdObject

eitherStringOrChipIdObject : Decoder ChipId
eitherStringOrChipIdObject =
    oneOf
        [ string |> map ChipIdString
        , chipIdObjectDecoder |> map ChipIdObject
        ]
```